# NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<dynamic>

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been using flutter for a week now, I don't know really what I'm doing,
but I need to iterate marker data to show it on google maps, I'm using dummy data to
test.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:karage_test_1/app_bar.dart';
import 'package:karage_test_1/drawer.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class FireMap extends StatefulWidget {
@override
  _FireMapState createState() => _FireMapState();
}

class _FireMapState extends State<FireMap> {
  Future _future;
    Future<String> loadString() async =>
       await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data.json');
    List<Marker> allMarkers = [];
    @override
   void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _future = loadString();
  }
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        child:
         FutureBuilder<dynamic> (
            future: _future,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
               List<dynamic> parsedJson = jsonDecode(snapshot.data);
               print(parsedJson);
               allMarkers = parsedJson.map((e) {
               return Marker(
                    markerId: MarkerId(e['nam']),
                    position: LatLng(e[['coord'][0]], e[['cooord'][1]]));
               }).toList();
              return GoogleMap(
                 initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                 target: LatLng(31.9539, 35.9106),
                 zoom: 15,
               ),
               markers: Set.from(allMarkers),
               );
            },
        ))]);
     } 
    }
```

And Im getting this error:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<dynamic>(dirty, state: 
_FutureBuilderState<dynamic>#21889):
The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length
```

How can I solve it, keep in mind that im new to flutter and dart

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a problem in `jsonDecode()` method, please add that method also to resolve the issue.

At first snapshot.data is null and I'm thinking that you are trying to iterate snapshot.data and it is throwing the exception. Also you can call `snapshot.hasData()` method to check data is available or not.